# Appending url query

Tags: node.js, express, pug

this is the first time I create an application using NodeJS and I need a little help. I want to append a query in the url by clicking a button.

The website has a search box, and navigation for sorting(most viewed,most downloaded)

Ex:

When searching for `foo`, the url will be like this.

`localhost:3000/search?q=foo`

But when i clicked the <kbd>most viewed</kbd> button, the result will be

`localhost:3000/search?tab=views`

**Expected result**

`localhost:3000/search?q=foo&tab=views`

Comment: You should probably use client side javascript

Comment: I am looking for a complete answer.

Comment: So basically the question is: _How to combine two GET vars (of which one is constant and the other is an input field) in a form using Javascript?_ It's a bit hard to guess from the question what you actually want, but I think this is it... :-)

Comment: Yeah I think my question isn't clear enough. Thanks @Damon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I checked how stackoverflow.com handles the search. 
For example, I searched for "hello world" here in stackoverflow.

The url will be like `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hello+world`

And the button/links for the following will be:

relevance = https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=hello+world

newest= https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=hello+world

Sorry if the question is unclear but this is the solution I am looking for.